# How to implement Qabstractvideosurface and monitor video per frame in qtcreator?

Tags: c++, qt, video, qt-creator, qtmultimedia

I am using the media player example from qt examples and am trying to create  a custom video surface. I want to be able to manipulate the frames real time to do some operations on them(e.g. gaussian filter).
My code for the video surface looks like this:

```
QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat> VideoSurface::supportedPixelFormats(
        QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType handleType) const
{

Q_UNUSED(handleType);

       // Return the formats you will support
       return QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat>() << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB565;
}

bool VideoSurface::present(const QVideoFrame &frame)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(frame);
        // Handle the frame and do your processing
    return true;
}
```

Do I need to implement the start function to get it to work?
My code for the player looks like this:

```
    player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    // owned by PlaylistModel
    playlist = new QMediaPlaylist();
    player->setPlaylist(playlist);

    /*
    QVideoRendererControl* rendererControl = player->service()->requestControl<QVideoRendererControl*>();

    if (rendererControl)
            rendererControl->setSurface(videoSurf);
    else
            qDebug() << "QtVideoSource: Unable to get QVideoRenderControl for video integration. No video will be emitted from this video source.";
    */

//! [create-objs]

    connect(player, SIGNAL(durationChanged(qint64)), SLOT(durationChanged(qint64)));
    connect(player, SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)), SLOT(positionChanged(qint64)));
    connect(player, SIGNAL(metaDataChanged()), SLOT(metaDataChanged()));
    connect(playlist, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), SLOT(playlistPositionChanged(int)));
    connect(player, SIGNAL(mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)),
            this, SLOT(statusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)));
    connect(player, SIGNAL(bufferStatusChanged(int)), this, SLOT(bufferingProgress(int)));
    connect(player, SIGNAL(videoAvailableChanged(bool)), this, SLOT(videoAvailableChanged(bool)));
    connect(player, SIGNAL(error(QMediaPlayer::Error)), this, SLOT(displayErrorMessage()));


    VideoSurface* videoSurf = new VideoSurface();

    //Don't use video Widget, but the custom video surface
    videoWidget = new VideoWidget(this);

    player->setVideoOutput(videoSurf);
```

The player starts and the audio works like usual, the time counter goes as usual, but the display is black, there is no video. What should I do to see the frames? Also I would be curious to know about the commented part with QVideoRendererControl. I got it from some site and would like to know, is it an alternative way to manipulate the frames instead of the present function or what is it good for?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Hey, did you ever solve this problem? I have stumbled across a similar problem where I have to manipulate feed coming from camera and then send to QML for displaying.

Comment: No, I actually gave up on the project back then. I hope I don't demotivate too much;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean to use QAbstractVideoSurface instead of QAbstractVideoBuffer?
In that case you also need to implement the isFormatSupported and supportedPixelFormats functions. And ofcourse start it.

Comment: Do you mean writing `supportedPixelFormats(QAbstractVideoSurface handleType) const` ? If I do so I get an cannot declare parameter 'handleType' to be of abstract type 'QAbstractVideoSurface'
    QAbstractVideoSurface handleType ) const;
error. Do you mean by starting it implementing the start function? I used a snippet from [link](http://code.google.com/p/dviz/source/browse/trunk/src/glvidtex/QtVideoSource.cpp) But my video is in yuv420p format and I can't convert it to qimage. Do I really need isFormatSupported? The present function is called repeatedly, I tested with a print command in it.